# git pre-commit hook isort and black keep failing for a python project

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a project using dash to commit, but it fails when I try to commit the following part:

```
@app_dash.callback(
    Output("output_data_upload", "figure"),
    [Input("radioitems_x_axis", "value"), Input("checklist_y_axis", "value")],
    [State("data_store", "data")],
)
def update_figure(
    selected_signal_of_x_axis: str, selected_signal_of_y_axis: list, data: list
) -> go.Figure:
    """
    Plot the figure based on the selections of users.

    :param selected_signal_of_x_axis: a selected signal for x-ordination
    :type selected_signal_of_x_axis: str
    :param selected_signal_of_y_axis: a/several selected signal(s) for y-ordination
    :type selected_signal_of_y_axis: list
    :param data: the filtered data of the uploaded documents
    :type data: list
    :return fig: the figure which is showed on the website based on the selection of users.
    :rtype: go.Figure
    """
    fig = fig_plotting.data_plot(
        selected_signal_of_x_axis, selected_signal_of_y_axis, data
    )
    return fig
```

The information of TortoiseGit is like this:

```
black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- files were modified by this hook

reformatted ReportGeneration\subpages\measurement_chart_plot.py

All done! \u2728 \U0001f370 \u2728
1 file reformatted.

nbstripout...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
isort (python)...........................................................Failed
- hook id: isort
- files were modified by this hook

Fixing C:\Users\OneDrive - User\ReportGeneration\subpages\measurement_chart_plot.py

nbqa-black...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
nbqa-isort...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
nbqa-pylint..........................................(no files to check)Skipped
nbqa-ruff............................................(no files to check)Skipped
ruff.....................................................................Passed
[INFO] Restored changes from C:\Users\.cache\pre-commit\patch17047452450-72632.
```

Is there anyone who could tell me how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

by default `isort`'s formatting is not compatible with `black`

what's happening is black is formatting it one way and then isort is changing it back

you can configure isort to format it in a black compatible way by setting `profile = black` in its config file

alternatively you can use another import sorter which is compatible with black (such as my `reorder-python-imports`)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit